# Listbox, how to get the value of chosen element?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I am creating a GUI in Tkinter and I just started using listbox, how can I give my items a value? Is that possible? For instance, if my listbox have items like 'Press here to print nr 7', 'Press here to print nr 45', 'Press here to print nr 112', then I want the first item to have the value 7 and the second one 45 and so on, just like you can do with radio buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`listbox` as default doesn't run any function when you click item. You have to assign/bind event `'<<ListboxSelect>>'` with name of function which should be executed after clicking. And inside this function you can get selection from `listbox`

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- function ---

def on_selection(event):
    # here you can get selected element

    print('previous:', listbox.get('active'))
    print(' current:', listbox.get(listbox.curselection()))

    # or using `event`

    #print('event:', event)
    #print('widget:', event.widget)
    print('(event) previous:', event.widget.get('active'))
    print('(event)  current:', event.widget.get(event.widget.curselection()))

    print('---')

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
listbox.pack()

listbox.insert(1, 'Hello 1')
listbox.insert(2, 'Hello 2')
listbox.insert(3, 'Hello 3')
listbox.insert(4, 'Hello 4')

listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', on_selection)

root.mainloop()
```